# SQL: split string and count occurances by week

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, aggregate-functions

I've written a SQL query that looks like this:

```
SELECT date_trunc('week', created_at)::date AS week, posted_to AS providers
FROM documents
GROUP BY week, providers
ORDER BY week, providers
```

A typical row out looks like this:

```
2017-05-08  {facebook_2214,facebook_2215,facebook_2216,twitter_2219}
```

I want to count the number of times the word `facebook` or `twitter` or `linkedin` or others occurs per week, so to group by `facebook` for this week should return `3`, and `twitter` for this week should return `1`. The column type is an array.

Any ideas? I'd rather it be programatic than write an `AS facebook` for each possible result, but beggars can't be choosers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Extract a provider name using `split_part()` and count sum in groups by date, provider:

```
with my_data(date, providers) as (
values
    ('2017-05-08', '{facebook_2214,facebook_2215,facebook_2216,twitter_2219}'::text[]),
    ('2017-05-15', '{twitter_2220,twitter_2221,linkedin_2222}')
)

select date, provider, count(*)
from (
    select date, split_part(u, '_', 1) as provider
    from my_data,
    unnest(providers) u
    ) s
group by 1, 2
order by 1, 2;

    date    | provider | count 
------------+----------+-------
 2017-05-08 | facebook |     3
 2017-05-08 | twitter  |     1
 2017-05-15 | linkedin |     1
 2017-05-15 | twitter  |     2
(4 rows)
```

Comment: That is straight-up _beautiful_. Thank-you!